# Flask GAE app giving error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

I created a flask app which is working fine on pythonanywhere but when i deployed it on google app engine ,its giving error http://aapkatool.appspot.com/

here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect,url_for,render_template,flash,abort
import jinja2
import os
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def emi():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    p =int(request.form['enternumber1'])
    r=float(request.form['enternumber2'])
    R=(r/12)/100
    N =int(request.form['enternumber3'])
    Dp =int(request.form['enternumber4'])
    P=p-Dp
    B=(1+R)**N
    I=(B)/(B-1)

    EMI1 = (P) * (R) * (I)
    EMI="%.2f" %(EMI1)
    TAP1=EMI1*N
    TAP="%.2f" %(TAP1)
    TI=TAP1-P
    TI="%.2f" %(TI)



    return render_template('index.html', EMI=EMI,TAP=TAP,TI=TI,P=P,r=r,N=N,Dp=Dp)
  return render_template('index.html')
```

and here is my app.yaml code

```
application: aapkatool
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: initialize.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"

- name: markupsafe
  version: "latest"
```

and here is initialize.py code

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

from main import app

run_wsgi_app(app)
```

here is the complete error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle

    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1701, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1685, in wsgi_app

    with self.request_context(environ):

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1646, in request_context

    return RequestContext(self, environ)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\ctx.py", line 186, in __init__

    self.match_request()

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\ctx.py", line 204, in match_request

    self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1423, in match

    raise NotFound()

NotFound: 404: Not Found

INFO     2016-10-12 15:13:03,801 module.py:788] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2016-10-12 09:43:46,542 wsgi.py:279] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle

    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1701, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app

    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\main.py", line 13, in age2

    p =int(request.form['enternumber1'])

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\local.py", line 336, in __getattr__

    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\utils.py", line 77, in __get__

    value = self.func(obj)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 383, in form

    self._load_form_data()

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\flask\wrappers.py", line 129, in _load_form_data

    RequestBase._load_form_data(self)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 318, in _load_form_data

    data = parser.parse_from_environ(self.environ)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 164, in parse_from_environ

    return self.parse(stream, mimetype, content_length, options)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 188, in parse

    content_length, options)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 98, in wrapper

    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 209, in _parse_urlencoded

    errors=self.errors, cls=self.cls)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\urls.py", line 278, in url_decode_stream

    include_empty, errors))

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 330, in __init__

    for key, value in mapping or ():

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\urls.py", line 283, in _url_decode_impl

    for pair in pair_iter:

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 670, in make_chunk_iter

    stream = make_limited_stream(stream, limit)

  File "C:\Python27\ageapp\werkzeug\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 579, in make_limited_stream

    raise TypeError('stream not limited and no limit provided.')

TypeError: stream not limited and no limit provided.

INFO     2016-10-12 15:13:46,665 module.py:788] default: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

please help me why it is giving error.
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be working, what's the error?

Comment: please click on calculate then it will show error Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: same code working fine on http://kk268.pythonanywhere.com/emi-calc

Comment: You haven't commented if its working or not in the local development server.

Comment: its not working in local development server

Answer (score 0):

Is the `calculate` function defined in both deployments on http://kk268.pythonanywhere.com/emi-calc and http://aapkatool.appspot.com/ ? The only error I'm seeing in my browser is:

```
(index):145 Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined
onclick @ (index):145
```

and I don't see where the `calculate` function is defined.

Comment: Hi friendoflore ,thanks for your answer but in flask there is no need to define calculate function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you even have the `initialize.py` file at all. It doesn't look like you need it. The [`google.appengine.ext.webapp`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) package docs state that its for the deprecated Python 2.5 environment and you're rightfully using Python 2.7.

1. Change your `app.yaml`'s script handler to point instead to `main.app`.
2. Delete `initialize.py`.
3. Redeploy or better yet, test your code locally so that you will see what the exact error code is without having to redeploy. If it is only occuring on the deployed version, go into the [logging area of the Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) and expand the failing request to see the error code and problem code that you need to fix.

A sample starter project with Flask can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/hello_world), which is also referenced in the [Getting Started docs for App Engine with Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env). Also, get your [local development server running](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server) if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi BrettJ ,I deleteed initialize.py but still same error .I run it offline too.here is the error."  raise TypeError('stream not limited and no limit provided.')

TypeError: stream not limited and no limit provided.
"

Comment: There should be more helpful information in the output, such as the line number. You need to post the full context of the error.

Comment: Hi BrettJ .Thanks  for your reply .I have posted complete error message on my post .please check and let me know where I am doing wrong

Comment: I ran your app locally without a problem. I believe you have an issue with your dependencies. Where is Flask? Is it in your app directory? Try pip install -t lib/ flask and then create an appengine_config.py file with the following: from google.appengine.ext import vender and on the next line  vendor.add('lib').